# how to change number of items appearing in right-hand-side of the rule with apriori in R(arules)

Tags: r, arules

I am using the `arules` package.  So far for extracting association rules from a DB:

```
 items <- apriori(db, parameter = list(target = "frequent itemsets", 
                  support =0.1, confidence =0.5, minlen=2))
  rules <- ruleInduction(rules, db, control = list(verbose = TRUE))
  multioutput=as(closed_rules, "data.frame");
```

However, in the resulting rules, I am still getting rules with just 1 item in the RHS even if minlen=2.

Would you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The help file for `apriori` says:

> Note: Apriori only creates rules with one item in the RHS (Consequent)!

So I am afraid that there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah but it is also said that: These rules mean that no matter what other items are involved, the item in the RHS will appear with the probability given by the rule's confidence (which equals the support). If you want to avoid these rules then use the argument parameter=list(minlen=2).

Comment: @C.DAVID You omitted the part just before that which says: `The default value in APparameter for minlen is 1. This means that rules with only one item (i.e., an empty antecedent/LHS) like {} => {beer}  will be created. `  That is telling you how to avoid rules with an empty antecedent. `minlen=2` means that there must be at least one item on the LHS.